# How to use the 'extra' characters on a German keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I was thinking of keeping my keyboard set to German all the time, because it has all the letters that both German and English need. However, looking at the 'keyboard layout', I've noticed the German keyboard has a lot of characters I have no clue how to access.

It shows 4 characters for each key, seriously. By default, pressing any key types the one in the lower left. Holding shift types the one in the upper left. Its the ones on the right I can't access. Quite a lot of those characters would be quite useful to me. Besides, by < and > symbols only appear on the right side. I need those to type programs, which is the only reason why I have to keep my keyboard set to English most of the time.

How do I access these extra letter? I can find nothing about it. I did think about getting a German-language keyboard, but those don't show these extra characters at all. How do you use them?

Comment: are those a different color? if so the key you need has the same color. also do not forget alt and alt gr, control,  control gr. the Fn key and combo's of control/alt/shift.

Comment: No, they're all showing as the same color in the interface. All the text is black and the keys themselves are white and grey.

Comment: Try AltGr + key (usually the right hand side Alt key) to get the second level and shift + AltGr + key for the fourth. Does that work?

Comment: That does work yes. Sadly, it would seem that the German keyboard actually does NOT have equivalents to the < and > keys. Fml. Oh well, at least now I can access letters like æ, ø, ð, and þ.

Comment: @user8600 of course it does, there is no way it wouldn't. [Looks like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout) it should be on the same key as the pipe (`|`).

Comment: That's not the same layout my computer is telling me. The 'pipe' key prints » and ›. Neither of which python recognizes as < and >. I thought it would, but it does not. I have no idea what those symbols could be for. Strangely, the keyboard shows two characters for ß, the other ẞ being bigger than the one on the number line at the top.

Comment: Looking further down that page, the keyboard ubuntu is showing me is the one for linux, not the standard keyboard near the top.

Comment: Oh, its this 'dead' key I don't have access to. I thought it was the z key, but apparently they've mapped to a key between z and shift that isn't on my keyboard, nor does pressing any other key show it being pressed in the interface. Wtf?

Comment: Because Alt-Gr is on the right-hand side of the keyboard where almost all the keys that respond to it are, the German keyboard is fairly awkward when typing any of the additional characters (and who placed ß in the most inconvenient place imaginable?). I would recommend looking at the US International keyboard with dead keys instead. Type " followed by A for Ä, type ' followed by e for é, ~ followed by n for ñ etc. This layout gains you a lot more characters than the German one while not having to turn your right hand into a contortionist device, instead remaining mostly in the home position.

Answer (score 2):

These are usually accessed by pressing the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key (usually the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key that is on the right hand side of the keyboard) plus whatever key you want, to get the third level, and Shift + AltGr and whatever key you want to get to the fourth level.

This isn't specific to German keyboard layouts, but to any layout with multiple options per key, including the English International with dead keys and similar.